# How do I find whether a line is intersecting a circles with small radius on earth?

Tags: intersection, latitude-longitude

Algorithm mentioned in [how-to-pick-up-line-segments-which-is-inside-or-intersect-a-circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725842/how-to-pick-up-line-segments-which-is-inside-or-intersect-a-circle) seems to be working fine for circle with radius > 50 miles.

But when coming to circles with radius < 50 miles it's not working properly. Please let me know an efficient mechanism to handle all the cases.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to define "not working properly". Give specific values and unexpected results.